# Quais são as ferramentas(API's, bibliotecas, frameworks) necessárias para criação de gráficos e relatórios?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou querendo pegar dados por exemplo de um banco de dados e desenvolver gráficos desse tipo, segue a figura abaixo:

[image: Gráfico]

Se possível em vários formatos em pizza, em barras etc. E depois gerar um relatório desse tipo que possar ser salvo, por exemplo no formato .pdf ou .doc:

[image: Relatório]

Comment: Pedro, você pode usar alguma das bibliotecas de gráficos open-source, tem uma lista diversa neste site: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/40. Para o relatório em formato de tabela você pode usar um `TableLayout` ou um `ListView`.

Comment: @Wakim vou dar uma olhada.. em aplicacoes pra desktop java eu usava ireport pra ter relatorios personalizados... e possivel utilizar no android?

Comment: Que eu saiba não é possível, são plataformas diferentes, não sei se o jasper reports rodaria no Android, vale a pena uma busca...

Comment: Pedro, acabei pesquisando e vi que existe um SDK do Jasper Report. Ele é apenas um cliente de um servidor Jasper. Da uma olhada em http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/mobile-sdk-android

Comment: Olá, Pedro. Genericamente falando, sua pergunta não é ruim, mas para o formato do SOpt tem dois problemas; Um é que é um pouco ampla, pois vai depender muito do uso individual e gosto de cada um, pois Android é uma plataforma bem abrangente. O outro problema é que essas coisas mudam muito, e mesmo que alguém ponha uma pergunta bem completa, ela ficará desatualizada em bem pouco tempo. Não veja voto de fechamento como crítica, é apenas uma forma de organização e adequação. E em outros aspectos, suas perguntas andam melhorando, com a experiência vc pega o jeitão da coisa!.

Comment: @Bacco wryel me respondeu o que eu queria...

Comment: @PedroRangel eu já tinha visto a resposta, geralmente não voto correndo justamente para dar tempo de alguém solucionar o problema imediato para o autor. Mas há uma grande probabilidade que a resposta dada vá ficar desatualizada com o tempo, como comentei.

Comment: @Bacco de boas..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algumas API's de gráficos/report para android:

- [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/)
- [Android GraphView](http://android-graphview.org/)
- [AChartEngine](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)
- [ChartDroid](https://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/)
- [Google Charts (HTML 5)](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

API para escrever PDF dentro do android:

- [Android PDF Writer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apwlibrary/)
- [iText](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/) (para aplicativos comerciais, requer licença)
- [Se você estiver acima da API 19, pode optar por dar uma olhada na documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/pdf/PrintedPdfDocument.html)

[Para escrever uma simples imagem com texto como a que você citou, você pode usar a API Bitmap do própio Android](http://www.skoumal.net/en/android-how-draw-text-bitmap).

Comment: +1 pela sua resposta.. obrigado